# CardImg doesn't render images using reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, babeljs, reactstrap

I created an application using create-react-app. when I use reactstrap Bootstrap classes appears but images doesn't appears. Can someone help me to solve this issue please.

dishes data :

[https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/hwM3_kd5EeiV-Ap8VLXT-A_87d2bc70477911e8ac49a50cea1c6260_dishes.js?Expires=1632528000&Signature=VZ2c0BPB6TEASRXR3WNxwY9kObCA7H3oMSPlcPA43ItM5jA-YlWJZtLbrAdZw9pxpi6Q5CkbfZYxw38x4Y1waleJy2SLuzb-dDV6w9Jiz~KdyrYJlVNDpt7BCXGnTFlPsXBfhBgNLWRorZPThLKnc9A3RcwZ8QICHCEX1boOBHI_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/hwM3_kd5EeiV-Ap8VLXT-A_87d2bc70477911e8ac49a50cea1c6260_dishes.js?Expires=1632528000&Signature=VZ2c0BPB6TEASRXR3WNxwY9kObCA7H3oMSPlcPA43ItM5jA-YlWJZtLbrAdZw9pxpi6Q5CkbfZYxw38x4Y1waleJy2SLuzb-dDV6w9Jiz%7EKdyrYJlVNDpt7BCXGnTFlPsXBfhBgNLWRorZPThLKnc9A3RcwZ8QICHCEX1boOBHI_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

```
    <Card>
<CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardBody>
                          <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                          <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is not with Reactstrap. Rather your image path is incorrect.

Comment: @Rusty Thank you yeah that's the problem